# User behaviors analysis, stackoverflow public data dump

Tags: data-dump

I have a question - what would be the best way to figure out in which timezone particular user is situated based on the `location` field data? It seems like considerable amount of users have this field populated with some data, the form, however, is far from being normalized.

While I am figuring out ways to normalize users locations and infer timezones, I wonder, if someone did it before and could share some experience, or maybe (ideally) there is some magic webservice which I can ask for timezones by a given location?

So far I am running through fairly simple process - tokenizing the field, sorting, grouping by frequencies and assigning timezones manually based on my best knowledge.

Comment: Your question isn't specific to the SO data dump. It's a question about interpreting natural language location strings. Thus I think it fits SO better than meta.SO.

Comment: I think you are right, should I ask similar question there, or can I move my question over? I've posted in meta because I was targeting users who have experience with public data dump.

Comment: "considerable amount" is debatable [it's 22%](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82875) as at the last refresh of data.se. I also seem to remember that from a specific point it's a look up on Yahoo Placefinder API (that caused a few problems) but I can't find the reference.

Comment: thank you for the hints. I found quite a few good posts at SO. Well, you are right about the number, I wish there was more data. In fact, it's about 20K of different locations among 260K of users (out of ~1.3M) as per August 2012 dump. I use Lucene's tokenizer and [Goggle Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). It works well so far. I'll try Yahoo for unknown ones - like "on the Server Farm" ;)